# Adding picture to JFrame from another class java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, imageicon

I am trying to make a program that reads a file chosen by the user, and after reading the file - the suffix "txt" is changed to "gif" and the file is saved as a picture (which is in the same catalogue as the file). The thing is, this picture variable gets its value in the "actionPerformed-method" and after that I want to add it to a frame in another class- but it doesn't show. Here's the code in my OptionsPane-class:

```
public class OptionsPane extends JComponent implements ActionListener{

    private JButton buttonOne = new JButton("Alt.1");
    private JButton buttonTwo = new JButton("Alt.2");
    private JButton buttonThree = new JButton("Alt.3");
    private int option;
    private JButton buttonChoose = new JButton("Choose file"); 
    private FileHandler filehandler; 
    private String picture;
    private JLabel picLabel; 

    public OptionsPane(){

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Choose optimization method", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        JPanel subPanel = new JPanel(); 
        label.setForeground(Color.CYAN); 
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));   
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        this.add(label);
        buttonOne.addActionListener(this);
        buttonTwo.addActionListener(this);
        buttonThree.addActionListener(this);
        buttonChoose.addActionListener(this);

        subPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        subPanel.add(buttonOne);
        subPanel.add(buttonTwo);
        subPanel.add(buttonThree);
        subPanel.add(buttonChoose);
        this.add(subPanel);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == buttonOne){
            option = 1;
            System.out.println("You clicked button 1!");
        }else if(e.getSource() == buttonTwo){
            option = 2;
            System.out.println("You clicked button 2!");
        }else if(e.getSource() == buttonThree){
            option = 3;
            System.out.println("You clicked button 3!");
        }else if(e.getSource() == buttonChoose){
            System.out.println("hello");
            option = 4; 
            filehandler = new FileHandler(); 
            filehandler.read();
            picture = filehandler.getFilePath().replaceFirst("txt", "gif"); 
            picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(picture));
            this.add(picLabel); 
        }
    }
}
```

The frame is in the "MainFrame"-class, which looks like this at the moment:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 
    private String picture; 
    private JLabel picLabel;
    public MainFrame(){

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1300, 800)); 
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        OptionsPane optionspane = new OptionsPane(); 
        frame.add(optionspane);

        frame.pack(); 
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(true);
    }
}
```

Why isn't the picture visible in the mainframe?

**EDIT**
It works now!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22380387/3271504

Thank you for your help @arooaroo . I tried to write down some of what you wrote, but it still didn't work when I wanted to add an image based on what file the user had chosen (for example if the user chose file text1.txt i wanted the corresponding picture "text1.gif" to show up). *With your help,* the picture showed up when I typed a specific pathway with "/"-slashes, but when I chose a file and tried to load the picture from the file pathway, it didn't show and that is because it had backslashes in the pathways. This is how it should be (such an irritating problem):

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == buttonOne){
        option = 1;
        System.out.println("You clicked button 1!");
    }else if(e.getSource() == buttonTwo){
        option = 2;
        System.out.println("You clicked button 2!");
    }else if(e.getSource() == buttonThree){
        option = 3;
        System.out.println("You clicked button 3!");
    }else if(e.getSource() == buttonChoose){
    filehandler = new FileHandler(); 
    filehandler.read();
    filepath = filehandler.getFilePath(); 
    picture = filepath.replaceFirst("txt", "gif");
    picture = picture.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(picture);
    mainFrame.setPicture(icon);

}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is the file actually a gif? If so, why is the extension .txt in the first place? Secondly, you need to do replaceLast instead of replaceFirst to replace the extension.

Comment: There is a file and a picture with the same name but different endings, the file having "txt" and the picture "gif". The user chooses the textfile, and after that I want to be able to find the corresponding picture by changing the txt to gif. This part works (it finds the corresponding picture), it's just that the picture doesn't show up in the frame now.

Answer (score 0):

Once you separate your GUI code in to separate classes - which is a Good Thing - you will find the eternal challenge for GUI programming is allowing for clean communication between them where there are inter-dependencies.

In this instance perhaps the simplest approach is to pass in a reference of `MainFrame` into `OptionsPane`.

Let's assume you create an additional method in `MainFrame` for setting the picture:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{

  // all instance vars as before

  public MainFrame() {
     // same as before except for this line...
     OptionsPane optionspane = new OptionsPane(this); 
  }

  public void setPicture(JLabel pictureLabel) {
     // add code here for adding the picture...
     // That's an exercise for yourself, or another question ;)
  }

}
```

Then in your OptionsPane class:

```
....
private MainFrame mainFrame;  // add a new instance var

public OptionsPane(MainFrame mainFrame) {
  this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
  // ... rest of the code same as before
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //...
        picture = filehandler.getFilePath().replaceFirst("txt", "gif"); 
        picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(picture));
        mainFrame.setPicture(picLabel); // <-- This is where you communicate with the mainFrame instance 
    //...
}
```

**EDIT**

Although my original answer provided a valid and correct solution, it's clear that the OP requires a fully working example, including the code to load display the resulting image. Here's a sample program.

```
public class OptionsPane extends JComponent implements ActionListener {

    private JButton buttonOne = new JButton("Alt.1");
    private JButton buttonTwo = new JButton("Alt.2");
    private JButton buttonThree = new JButton("Alt.3");
    private int option;
    private JButton buttonChoose = new JButton("Choose file");
    private String picture;
    private JLabel picLabel;
    private MainFrame mainFrame;

    public OptionsPane(MainFrame mainFrame) {
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Choose optimization method", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();
        label.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        this.add(label);
        buttonOne.addActionListener(this);
        buttonTwo.addActionListener(this);
        buttonThree.addActionListener(this);
        buttonChoose.addActionListener(this);

        subPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        subPanel.add(buttonOne);
        subPanel.add(buttonTwo);
        subPanel.add(buttonThree);
        subPanel.add(buttonChoose);
        this.add(subPanel);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // For sake of simplicity I'm ignoring the original button logic here
        // and focussing on just getting an icon loaded in the parent frame...

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("/path/to/test/image.png");
        // Just pass the icon itself rather than a new label.
        mainFrame.setPicture(icon);

    }
}


public class MainFrame {
    // No need to extend JFrame if you're using a JFrame instance variable
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JLabel picLabel;

    private JPanel mainPanel;
    public MainFrame() {
        mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1300, 800));

        OptionsPane optionspane = new OptionsPane(this);
        mainPanel.add(optionspane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        picLabel = new JLabel();
        picLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(picLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(true);
    }

    public void setPicture(ImageIcon icon) {
        picLabel.setIcon(icon);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainFrame();
    }
}
```

Note I've done a couple of things differently. Personally I always create a `JPanel` and set that up as the primary layer rather and add that directly to the frame rather than messing with the rootPane. And I used the `BorderLayout` in this example as it's much simpler.

The other thing is to add the `JLabel` which is to hold the picture to the GUI in the initial set up. Then you'll see I'm only changing its icon in the `setPicture()` method rather than adding a new `JLabel` on each instance.

Comment: Thank you! I've done that, to try if it works. In the "exercise"-part, I wrote: 
public void setPicture(JLabel pictureLabel){
  frame.add(pictureLabel);
}

Although the picture still doesn't show. Am I totally wrong here?

Comment: I really can't figure it out.

Comment: @keyboardSurfer On first glance that logic seems OK but you're missing  something: if you add a component to a frame after it's visible you'll then have to call repaint() or revalidate() (I can't remember which, may be both!)

Comment: I've done that and it still doesn't show. I'm telling you man, this code is magic..

Comment: @keyboardSurfer I've updated my answer to include another fully working example program.

Comment: Now I've edited my question with a comment to you (didn't know how to answer with some code otherwise). Please check it! 
Cheers,

Comment: @keyboardSurfer Java can cope with unix-like paths with forward slashes (like I used in my example because I'm on OSX) or Windows paths with backslashes, although you'll find that they are escaped eg. `"c:\\a\\sample\\path\\to\\file.txt"`. Why not double check that the file you think you're loading actually exists: `boolean exists = new File(filepath).exists();` I have no idea what that FileHandler class is doing and what it's returning. I'd strongly recommend spinning this off to a separate question though rather than appending additional requests to the original post.